# PowerShellGet - A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AcceptLicense'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following script as part of an automated install:

```
 if (Get-InstalledModule -Name PowerShellGet) {    
 
     $version = (Get-InstalledModule -Name PowerShellGet).Version
 
     if ([version]$version -gt [version]1.6)
     {
       Write-Host "PowerShellGet Module already installed."
     } else {
       Write-Host "Installing PowerShellGet"
       Install-Module PowerShellGet -MinimumVersion 1.6 -Force -AllowClobber
       Write-Host "PowerShellGet Module Installed."
     }
 } 
 else {
    Write-Host "Installing PowerShellGet"
    Install-Module PowerShellGet -MinimumVersion 1.6 -Force -AllowClobber
    Write-Host "PowerShellGet Module Installed."        
 }

 Import-Module -Name PowerShellGet -MinimumVersion 1.6
 Import-Module -Name PackageManagement -MinimumVersion 1.4.8.1

 Write-Host "Checking if SqlChangeAutomation installed.."
    
 if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name SqlChangeAutomation) {
     Write-Host "SqlChangeAutomation Module Already Installed"
 } 
 else {
     Write-Host "Installing SqlChangeAutomation"
     Install-Module -Name SqlChangeAutomation -RequiredVersion 4.0.19294.12888 -AcceptLicense -Force
 }
```

However it falls over with the following error:

```
Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AcceptLicense'.
At C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:9711 char:68
+ ... talledPackages = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Package], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

It seems to be running the right version of PowerShellGet and I have imported the latest version of PackageManagement.

The script needs to run without prompting to accept licences

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. There is simply no `-AcceptLicense` parameter on the [`Install-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/packagemanagement/install-package) cmdlet for the `PackageByInputObject` and `PackageBySearch` parametersets. I encourage you to raise a formal bug report at https://github.com/PowerShell/PackageManagementProviderResource/issues

Comment: The only way I could get this to work was to first install the updated PowerShellGet module and then manually (or in code outside of powershell) delete the older version of PowerShellGet from C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet and C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet